# Changing the style (forecolor) of a DataGridViewComboBoxCell Selected Item

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I would really like to change the style of the selected item of a single DataGridVeiwComboBox control.

There is a database that feeds information into my DataGridView, and if for some reason, the data is invalid, I would like to notify the user somehow.  I have decided to make the dropdown text font red, and background blue so it can stand out in a list of hundreds of rows.

When there is invalid data (meaning the data coming form the database is not one of the options in the dropdown list) the DataError callback is invoked:

```
private void OnDataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
    ((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(((DataGridView)(sender))[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex])).Style = style;
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

However this results in the following:

[image]

I dont want the dropdown the change, I want the '0' thats the selected value to change.

Is there another way to notify the user that the value is invalid?  I dont want to create a list and present it to the user, the number of rows can be quite large.

Comment: Seems to me that the display of a grid cell is not the appropriate place to validate data.  Perhaps you should question the reason you are displaying "invalid" data in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other location where this can be addressed without major restructuring to the application as a whole.  This is just part of an ever continuing issue where old databases are being used with new front ends, where the old values in the DB have been OBE over the years, and never changed.  The point of this exercise is to flesh out these failures, while still allowing work to be done.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no straightforward approach to achieve your goal.

1. Create custom "Column", "Cell" and "EditingControl" classes. Create custom `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` and override the `OnDrawItem` method to draw the item with custom colors.
2. Create the required combobox column with the custom `ComboBoxColumn` classes, add it to the grid and bind the data. If you set the `DataPropertyName` property of your column then when your data is bound that data column will get bound to your grid column. The DataGridView will generate other columns automatically.